# Updating NSDictionary inside an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries`. I need the updated `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries` with value of one of the dictionary key updated with new value.

Please see below the `NSArray` structure. I want to update the value for `Key3` inside this structure if `Key1` matches with some value (e.g. 2).  What would the fastest way of doing this. I do not want to use traditional For loop.

```
[myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.Key3"];

<__NSCFArray 0xe70c10>(
{
    Key1 = 1;
    Key2 = "New Location";
    Key3 =     (
        Data1,
        Data2,
        Data3
    );
},
{
    Key1 = 2;
    Key2 = "Old Location";
    Key3 =     (
        Data1,
        Data2,
        Data4
    );
}
)
```

Comment: Basically you just convert everything to mutable (I don't know that there's a "deep mutable copy" function, but if you're getting the structure from NSJSONSerialization you can tell it to give you mutable stuff), then locate the dictionary and change the element, just as you would with a stand-alone dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can solve it by using predicates:

```
NSArray *dictionaryArray;
NSNumber *key =@2;
NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Key1=%@",key];
NSArray *result =[dictionaryArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

result array now has all dictionaries having (key1 = 2)

Dictionarys can't be edited directly, they must be NSMutableDictionary to edit. Assuming they are NSMutableDictionary instances:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic =result[0];
[dic setObject:someObject forKey:@"key3"];
```

Comment: Isn't the predicate using a loop internally

Comment: unless you goto each object you cant say whether you got the result or not.So, predicates have internal methodology , which makes happen in fast way i guess.

Comment: Actually the inner dictionaries are not mutable so I am getting exception while updating them. Is there any quick way of mutating them inside the array.

Comment: create a new mutableArray from the original array, and find index of the required Dictionary using indexOfObject. using that index, use replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject method of mutableArray to replace it with new dictionary. to withObject pass the new modified dictionary. Now oldarray = [NSArray arraywitharray:mutableArray];

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that you already have an array containing all mutable dictionaries. The first step is to get what dictionaries you need to change:

```
NSPredicate* predicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"Key1=2"];
NSArray* filteredArray= [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
```

The second step is to replace the Key3 value for each object in the array. If you execute a selector on an array, and `NSArray` doesn't respond to that selector, the selector is performed on it's objects:

```
[filteredArray performSelector: @selector(setValue:forKey:) withObject: someValue withObject: @"Key3"];
```

After this statement you don't need to replace any object in `myArray`, because the filtered array contains the same objects that are in `myArray`, which are mutable dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I would also go for predicates as @santhu stated on his answer. However, I want to point that when searching an unsorted array linear search (that is, looping through every object and checking if it's the wanted one) is optimal. Probably predicates will provide an speed-up due to their internal routines, but a predicate will still execute the "traditional for loop" you want to avoid and thus the speed-up will not be very significant.

There are other searching algorithms which provide a significant speed-up, but they are only valid for sorted databases ([unless you have a quantum iPhone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm) ;) ).

If you are interested on this topic, [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~andria/csc/108s01/lecture/slides/lec12_complexity.html) you can find some types of search algorithms with an analysis of their complexity.

Comment: Yeah, I think there's a myth that using predicates or some such is faster than the obvious explicit loop, simply because you don't see the loop in your code.  In fact, the loop must be there, and whether predicates can do it faster is questionable.  Keep in mind that the predicate must devote a considerable amount of time (probably the lion's share, if there are only a handful of elements to check) simply parsing the predicate argument.